# SurfaceFlinger: dimensions too large 16777215 x 300

Tags: android, webrtc, surfaceview

I wrapped SurfaceViewRenderer  in Linearlayout and programmatically I add it into Linearlayout(id is dynamic_layout) which is already wrapped

**I am adding  subview into this view**

```
<HorizontalScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/dynamic_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                </LinearLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>
```

**this is subView**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/remote_video_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
            android:id="@+id/remote_video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

**This is java code**

```
 mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    RtcAdapter.this.totalConnection = totalConnection;
                    for (int i = 0; i < totalConnection; i++) {
                        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mActivity);
                        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_adapter, null);
                        mLinearLayout_papa.addView(view);
                        mList.add(new VideoViewLayout(R.id.remote_video_layout, RtcAdapter.this, R.id.remote_video_view, i, view));
                    }
                }
            });
```

This is my **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gwl.webrtcnewgradle">
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture" />
    <supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_OES_compressed_paletted_texture" />
<supports-gl-texture android:name="GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

this is app gradle app/build

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gwl.webrtcnewgradle"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'org.webrtc:google-webrtc:1.0.+'
    compile('io.socket:socket.io-client:0.8.3') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
}
```

This is SurfaceViewRenderer class

```
//
// Source code recreated from a .class file by IntelliJ IDEA
// (powered by Fernflower decompiler)
//

package org.webrtc;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
import org.webrtc.EglRenderer.FrameListener;
import org.webrtc.RendererCommon.GlDrawer;
import org.webrtc.RendererCommon.RendererEvents;
import org.webrtc.RendererCommon.ScalingType;
import org.webrtc.RendererCommon.VideoLayoutMeasure;
import org.webrtc.VideoRenderer.Callbacks;
import org.webrtc.VideoRenderer.I420Frame;

public class SurfaceViewRenderer extends SurfaceView implements Callback, Callbacks, VideoSink, RendererEvents {
    private static final String TAG = "SurfaceViewRenderer";
    private final String resourceName = this.getResourceName();
    private final VideoLayoutMeasure videoLayoutMeasure = new VideoLayoutMeasure();
    private final SurfaceEglRenderer eglRenderer;
    private RendererEvents rendererEvents;
    private int rotatedFrameWidth;
    private int rotatedFrameHeight;
    private boolean enableFixedSize;
    private int surfaceWidth;
    private int surfaceHeight;

    public SurfaceViewRenderer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.eglRenderer = new SurfaceEglRenderer(this.resourceName);
        this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        this.getHolder().addCallback(this.eglRenderer);
    }

    public SurfaceViewRenderer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.eglRenderer = new SurfaceEglRenderer(this.resourceName);
        this.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        this.getHolder().addCallback(this.eglRenderer);
    }

    public void init(org.webrtc.EglBase.Context sharedContext, RendererEvents rendererEvents) {
        this.init(sharedContext, rendererEvents, EglBase.CONFIG_PLAIN, new GlRectDrawer());
    }

    public void init(org.webrtc.EglBase.Context sharedContext, RendererEvents rendererEvents, int[] configAttributes, GlDrawer drawer) {
        ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
        this.rendererEvents = rendererEvents;
        this.rotatedFrameWidth = 0;
        this.rotatedFrameHeight = 0;
        this.eglRenderer.init(sharedContext, this, configAttributes, drawer);
    }

    public void release() {
        this.eglRenderer.release();
    }

    public void addFrameListener(FrameListener listener, float scale, GlDrawer drawerParam) {
        this.eglRenderer.addFrameListener(listener, scale, drawerParam);
    }

    public void addFrameListener(FrameListener listener, float scale) {
        this.eglRenderer.addFrameListener(listener, scale);
    }

    public void removeFrameListener(FrameListener listener) {
        this.eglRenderer.removeFrameListener(listener);
    }

    public void setEnableHardwareScaler(boolean enabled) {
        ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
        this.enableFixedSize = enabled;
        this.updateSurfaceSize();
    }

    public void setMirror(boolean mirror) {
        this.eglRenderer.setMirror(mirror);
    }

    public void setScalingType(ScalingType scalingType) {
        ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
        this.videoLayoutMeasure.setScalingType(scalingType);
        this.requestLayout();
    }

    public void setScalingType(ScalingType scalingTypeMatchOrientation, ScalingType scalingTypeMismatchOrientation) {
        ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
        this.videoLayoutMeasure.setScalingType(scalingTypeMatchOrientation, scalingTypeMismatchOrientation);
        this.requestLayout();
    }

    public void setFpsReduction(float fps) {
        this.eglRenderer.setFpsReduction(fps);
    }

    public void disableFpsReduction() {
        this.eglRenderer.disableFpsReduction();
    }

    public void pauseVideo() {
        this.eglRenderer.pauseVideo();
    }

    public void renderFrame(I420Frame frame) {
        this.eglRenderer.renderFrame(frame);
    }

    public void onFrame(VideoFrame frame) {
        this.eglRenderer.onFrame(frame);
    }

    protected void onMeasure(int widthSpec, int heightSpec) {
        ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
        Point size = this.videoLayoutMeasure.measure(widthSpec, heightSpec, this.rotatedFrameWidth, this.rotatedFrameHeight);
        this.setMeasuredDimension(size.x, size.y);
        this.logD("onMeasure(). New size: " + size.x + "x" + size.y);
    }

    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
        this.eglRenderer.setLayoutAspectRatio((float)(right - left) / (float)(bottom - top));
        this.updateSurfaceSize();
    }

    private void updateSurfaceSize() {
        ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
        if(this.enableFixedSize && this.rotatedFrameWidth != 0 && this.rotatedFrameHeight != 0 && this.getWidth() != 0 && this.getHeight() != 0) {
            float layoutAspectRatio = (float)this.getWidth() / (float)this.getHeight();
            float frameAspectRatio = (float)this.rotatedFrameWidth / (float)this.rotatedFrameHeight;
            int drawnFrameWidth;
            int drawnFrameHeight;
            if(frameAspectRatio > layoutAspectRatio) {
                drawnFrameWidth = (int)((float)this.rotatedFrameHeight * layoutAspectRatio);
                drawnFrameHeight = this.rotatedFrameHeight;
            } else {
                drawnFrameWidth = this.rotatedFrameWidth;
                drawnFrameHeight = (int)((float)this.rotatedFrameWidth / layoutAspectRatio);
            }

            int width = Math.min(this.getWidth(), drawnFrameWidth);
            int height = Math.min(this.getHeight(), drawnFrameHeight);
            this.logD("updateSurfaceSize. Layout size: " + this.getWidth() + "x" + this.getHeight() + ", frame size: " + this.rotatedFrameWidth + "x" + this.rotatedFrameHeight + ", requested surface size: " + width + "x" + height + ", old surface size: " + this.surfaceWidth + "x" + this.surfaceHeight);
            if(width != this.surfaceWidth || height != this.surfaceHeight) {
                this.surfaceWidth = width;
                this.surfaceHeight = height;
                this.getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height);
            }
        } else {
            this.surfaceWidth = this.surfaceHeight = 0;
            this.getHolder().setSizeFromLayout();
        }

    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        ThreadUtils.checkIsOnMainThread();
        this.surfaceWidth = this.surfaceHeight = 0;
        this.updateSurfaceSize();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    }

    private String getResourceName() {
        try {
            return this.getResources().getResourceEntryName(this.getId());
        } catch (NotFoundException var2) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    public void clearImage() {
        this.eglRenderer.clearImage();
    }

    public void onFirstFrameRendered() {
        if(this.rendererEvents != null) {
            this.rendererEvents.onFirstFrameRendered();
        }

    }

    public void onFrameResolutionChanged(int videoWidth, int videoHeight, int rotation) {
        if(this.rendererEvents != null) {
            this.rendererEvents.onFrameResolutionChanged(videoWidth, videoHeight, rotation);
        }

        int rotatedWidth = rotation != 0 && rotation != 180?videoHeight:videoWidth;
        int rotatedHeight = rotation != 0 && rotation != 180?videoWidth:videoHeight;
        this.postOrRun(new SurfaceViewRenderer$$Lambda$0(this, rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight));
    }

    private void postOrRun(Runnable r) {
        if(Thread.currentThread() == Looper.getMainLooper().getThread()) {
            r.run();
        } else {
            this.post(r);
        }

    }

    private void logD(String string) {
        Logging.d("SurfaceViewRenderer", this.resourceName + ": " + string);
    }
}
```

My code is working good in Pixel but in other devices like  HTC and S7 
 edge. I got following exception.

```
SurfaceFlinger: dimensions too large 16777215 x 300
SurfaceFlinger: createNormalLayer() failed (Invalid argument)
SurfaceComposerClient: SurfaceComposerClient::createSurface error Invalid argument
```

Comment: 16 millions (nearly 17) seems a LARGE number, effectively...

Comment: How to change the size of SufaceViewRenderer

Comment: I'd google some tutorial on SurfaceView. Try `surfaceview android`

Comment: I tried this code but not working



@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Rect rect = holder.getSurfaceFrame();
        if (rect.width() > maxWidth || rect.height() > maxHeight) {
            holder.setFixedSize(maxWidth, maxHeight);
        }
    }

Comment: Then you missed something - maybe a single line. Or maybe some setting in the Manifest and/or the gradle settings.

Comment: hi, Bernoulli Gate, I update the question with manifest and gradle, please check once

Comment: post `SurfaceViewRenderer` code

Comment: btw did you try: `inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_adapter, mLinearLayout_papa, false)`?

Comment: @BernoulliGate its not nearly 17 millions: it is *0xffffff*

Comment: @pskink So... 16777215 is not "nearly 17 millions"? since when?

Comment: @BernoulliGate indeed, thank you for enlightenment that it is `"LARGE number, effectively"` too, i did not know that...

Comment: @pskink OK, now you know.

Comment: @BernoulliGate so do you really do not see any difference between 16777215 and for example 12345678? both are ordinary numbers to you? really? and the fact that the first is 0xffffff is just an accident?

Comment: @pskink Well, I do see a lot of difference between nearly 17 Millions and nearly 12.5 Millions.

Comment: @BernoulliGate aha good luck then

Comment: @pskink If I could have only the difference (in pounds), I'd be rich. ;)

Comment: Bernoulli  hi , I update question and past surfaceViewRender class, please check it

Comment: so what do you have on the logcat: `onMeasure(). New size: ???x???` ?

Comment: @pskink remote_video_view: onMeasure(). New size: 2147483647x525

Comment: btw did you try: inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_adapter, mLinearLayout_papa, false)? – pskink 16 hours ago

I tried this also

Comment: 2147483647 is 0x7fffffff and when it is masked with `View#MEASURED_SIZE_MASK` it gives 0x00ffffff which is exactly 16777215, i hope you now know how to fix it

Comment: and dont ask BernoulliGate about 2147483647 - he will tell you that it is even LARGER number, effectively - more that 2 billions ;-)

Comment: we set videoLayoutMeasure.measure width and height onMeasure() method

Comment: however if you still dont know how to fix it then check why `this.videoLayoutMeasure.measure` returns 2147483647 (which is `Integer.MAX_VALUE`) in `Point#x` field

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159148/discussion-between-rajendra-verma-and-pskink).